# HTML5 Video in HTML Email only autoplaying on Samsung in Landscape mode

Tags: android, html, email, html-email

For some reason this video will only autoplay in Landscape mode in an HTML email. It simply idles on portrait mode until you flip it to landscape mode. You also can't click the play button on the e-mail in portrait mode. Can anyone help me out? This is my code. Is this a playback error with Android/Samsung devices? Unfortunately I can't include the video because its proprietary.

```
<video width="600" height="626" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="video" controls>
        <source src="private/fullvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It will auto play on Outlook for Mac, etc. Alternatively I could set up media queries to show/hide the fallback div for Samsung devices, which would display a .GIF, but these media queries dont seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 video, even when "officially supported" by an email client, can be quite glitchy in practice. Eg. issue you're experiencing with a video working in landscape but not portrait sounds more like **an issue with the email client** than your code. There are [a few examples here](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email) to help bulletproof your video code for email, though I'm not sure anything in there directly addressed the landscape vs. portrait bug you're seeing.

Depending on what version of Android/Samsung devices you're referring to, media queries aren't supported, so that's why that might not be working. [Here are](https://litmus.com/community/learning/49-which-mobile-email-clients-support-media-queries) [two links](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/#mobile-support) that keep up to date info on media query support.